# Meaning of $(\mathfrak q :x)$ in ring theory (commutative algebra)

Tags: commutative-algebra

I see the following notation: for a ring $A,$ a prime ideal $\mathfrak q,$ and $x\in A$.
$$
(\mathfrak q :x) = (1).
$$
The question is: what does $(\mathfrak q :x)$ mean? The ideal generated by $\mathfrak q ,x?$ Then why do we need to use a colon?

Comment: Notation can change from author to author, but the colon that I am used to between ideals is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient).

Comment: My guess is that the definition is the one given by @plop and that the statement should have been $$(\mathfrak q:x)=\begin{cases}\mathfrak q&\text{if }x\notin\mathfrak q\\ (1)&\text{if }x\in\mathfrak q\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a ring $R$, my guess would be

$$(\mathfrak{q} : x) = \{r \in R : rx\in \mathfrak{q}\} $$

Since I've seen the same notation used for subsets $I, J\subset R$

$$(I : J) = \{r\in R: rJ\subseteq I\}$$

Comment: There's a problem: if $\mathfrak q$ is prime, we have $(\mathfrak q : x) = (1)$ iff $x\in\mathfrak q$. So we should know whether the above equality is a hypothesis on $x$.

Comment: @Bernard Good point, I did think that just after posting. Perhaps this was better posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Not necessarily, as it may help other people who are not accustomed to this notation.